# Write a query to return the list of unique names from table

Tags: sql

Here is the table:

```
table A (
 id    integer       primary key,
 name  varchar(20),
 age   integer
)
```

The interview question is:

Write a  query to return the list of unique names from table .

Here is my solution:

```
select id from A group by name;
```

My question: is this the efficient way to return the list of the unique names?

Comment: Your solution returns the `id`s, not the names, as requested.

Answer (score 1):

No, because you're returning the IDs, not the names. That query won't even work in many DBMS' because selected columns have to either be in the `group by` clause or have an aggregating function (like `max()` or `sum()` and so on) applied to them.

You would need:

```
select name from a group by name
```

It's usually even *more* efficient if the `name` column is indexed.

The other common way of doing this is:

```
select distinct name from a
```

Comment: assuming the name column is not indexed

Comment: @Secure, if the `name` column is not indexed, it will run slower. But that doesn't change the fact that you need the names rather than the IDs.

Comment: Neither of those queries is likely to be more efficient if "name" is indexed. In either case, all values of "name" must be retrieved, and the database can't get those values any faster from the index that from a full-table access. If you were trying to find a specific name, then an index would make it more efficient.

Comment: Sorry, Allan, I believe you're wrong. Indexing the column allows you to use the index rather than the data itself. Since the index is smaller than the full record, there are more rows read per disk read. It may not be a lot of performance increase (especially in this case where the rest of the record is not so large) but it is _some._ And, as the rest of the record gets larger, the efficiency ramps up.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM A
```

or

```
SELECT name FROM A GROUP BY name
```

both are well understood. As for which one is faster, it may depend on the RDBMS in question.

Answer (score 0):

Select Distinct name FROM A is possibly the best bet you can get. There is no concept of getting list. You can create a list in the programming language which is linked to your database.